# What's the use of placing "&", when you can execute without it?

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual-functions

I am learning currently learning *virtual* and came across this question:

> The following is the declaration for class Animal:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    void Introduce()
    {
        cout<<"This is base class Animal.\n";
    }
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
    // complete the code here
};
```

> Complete the code above to with `class` Dog has the public function `sound()` that
> overrides the public function `Introduce()` in `class` Animal. The class Dog’s
> function `Introduce()` should print the phrase “Dog barks.”. Test the class Animal
> and `class` Dog by instantiating objects of the two classes in the main driver program as
> shown in code below.

```
int main()
{
 Animal a; // instantiate an object of class Animal
 Dog d; // instantiate an object of class Dog
Dog &rD = d; // instantiate a reference to a class Dog and 
// initialize it to address of object d
 Animal *aptr; // declare a pointer to class Animal
aptr = &d; // assign the address of object d of class Dog to the 
//aptr pointer
 a.sound();
 d.sound();
 rD.sound();
 aptr->sound();
 return 0;
}
```

I completed the question and my solution is:

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
public:
    void Introduce()
    {
        cout<<"This is base class Animal.\n";
    }
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:

    void Introduce()
    {
        cout<<"This is Dog barking base class (Animal).\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
 Animal a; // instantiate an object of class Animal
 Dog d; // instantiate an object of class Dog
Dog &rD = d; // instantiate a reference to a class Dog and
// initialize it to address of object d
 Animal *aptr; // declare a pointer to class Animal
aptr = &d; // assign the address of object d of class Dog to the
//aptr pointer
 a.Introduce();
 d.Introduce();
 rD.Introduce();
 aptr->Introduce();
 return 0;
}
```

I successfully tested the code and the output was as [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPWjH.png):

But I have a question:

I can execute my program without `&` operator but why did the question still add a `&` for this code?

```
// I can execute my code without the pointer:
Dog rD = d;
```

But the code chose to use this:

```
Dog &rd = d;
```

Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: You'd have to ask whoever wrote that, to be sure of what exactly the purpose of this is. It might be to draw a parallel with how `aptr` gets set up, but that's just my guess.

Comment: Without the &, you’ve created a second Dog that is a copy of the first Dog.  If that’s what you wanted, it’s fine, but in some cases you just want a reference to the existing Dog (and some classes don’t allow themselves to be copied)

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently learning virtual

But you don't have `virtual` anywhere in your code. If `Animal::sound` were `virtual` you would observe that with `Dog& rD = d;` you will get polymorphic behavior but with `Dog rD = d;` you wouldn't.

---

off topic: `sound` is a bad name for a method. Functions and methods should be named with verbs, e.g. `make_sound`.

Comment: Sound is also a verb (meaning to emit noise)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes, but without context (e.g. "sound the horn", "the buzzer sounded") the first association of the word is with the noun. At least for me personally. Also it doesn't make sense to say "the animal sound" or "the dog sound" (as a verb). It does however make sense to say "the animal makes a sound".

Comment: "Sound the alarm." But I agree with bolov. I would expect `dog.sound();` to return an enum `WOOF` describing the sound the animal makes.